# why does friendly-id have add slug column on tabled and can't be found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I'm have article table

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
def change
  create_table :articles do |t|
    t.string :title
    t.text :body

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

end

followed [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) README

1). `rails generate friendly_id`

2.) add extend to `Article` model

```
 class Article < ApplicationRecord
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :title, use: :slugged'
 end
```

3). add `slug field to article table`

```
class AddSlugToArticle < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :articles, :slug, :string
    add_index :articles, :slug, unique: true
  end
end
```

open web browser `http://localhost:3000/article/new`
could see `rails terminal`

[image]
this is issue place in article controller:

```
def show
  @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @article.comments.order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 4)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: [@article, @comments], except: [:created_at, :updated_at] }
  end
end
```

this terminal error report:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ye, found this error, because not add parameter on strong params

```
 def article_params
   params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :catalog_id, :slug)
 end
```